# firejail : only let a program access localhost

Tags: networking, namespace, network-namespaces, sandbox, firejail

I have this local network service and this client program needing to access it. I am running them both as an unprivileged user.

I am looking for a way to sandbox the client using firejail, in a way that it cannot access network, except for localhost (or even better, except for that service).
first thing I tried was of course

```
firejail --net=lo program
```

But it didn’t work.

```
Error: cannot attach to lo device
```

I think I could work around it by creating a virtual network interface, for example veth0 and veth1, 
moving veth1 to a new network namespace in which I’d run the service
and using firejail to restrain the client to veth0

Is there a way to actually automate this setting in a firejail profile, so that all of these interfaces are created and veth1 is moved when I type

```
firejail server
```

(without having to run anything as root)?

Or is there a simpler way solve this problem? (I cannot run both the client and the service in the same namespace, because the service needs to access the network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use and option kind of like:

```
firejail --interface=eth0.vlan100 --ip=someipaddress someprogram
```

> Support for ipvlan driver was introduced  in  Linux
>                 kernel 3.19.

Found Here: [man firejail | Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/features-3/man-firejail/)

Comment: That command doesn't work for me, it gives the error "Error: no network device configured"

Comment: You still have to set up that virtual interface. That command is given as an example, I have no idea what your network interface is it could be eth0 wlan0 or eth1, wlan1 etc....

Comment: Problem is that having to setup the virtual interface means that some commands should be run as root (which contradicts what I asked), so if somebody has a better solution, I'll accept that one instead